# is it possible for iBeacon to act as just normal BLE data transmission module after connection?

Tags: bluetooth, ibeacon, firmware, ibeacon-android

i know that iBeacon use only advertising channel. which means there is no need connection.

im trying to make my own beacon module which send and receive data.

im curious about what makes the packet in iBeacon format(prefix /UUID / minor/ major/ TX) in communication ?

is it firmware?

let's assume that

when i make my iPhone act as iBeacon , it will send the advertising packet. which means it sends data in iBeacon format. but after turn off the app for iBeacon, i try to use my iphone
to send some files to laptop via Bluetooth low energy mode as usual.
then it will send data in bluetooth standard format. is this right?

given that situation, my iphone can be both iBeacon and just normal phone capable of bluetooth low energy.

i think also the beacon module can be like that. how about the product recently released? like estimote, redbearlab and so on. after connection, do they receive data?

Answer (score 0):

Every iBeacon product works a little differently, but it is common for a product to be connectable for configuration purposes over Bluetooth LE.

Radius Networks' [RadBeacon](http://www.radiusnetworks.com/radbeacon/), for example, has firmware that sends out its advertisement as needed to be a standard iBeacon.  The same firmware will allow a connection over Bluetooth LE, exchanging data with an external client (the RadBeacon app for iOS).  This connectability is outside standard iBeacon functionality, using proprietary techniques that are still part of the larger Bluetooth LE standard.

Your understanding is therefore correct.

Full disclosure: I am Chief Engineer at [Radius Networks](http://www.radiusnetworks.com).